# How can I replace vector values with ascending numbers using the same intervals

Tags: r

I am trying to replace values of a vector with different intervals, such that the intervals are numbered from 1 to last interval. For example,

```
x <- c(5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17)
```

I want to be like this:

```
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)
```

Is there a way to this automatically?

Thanks for any help.

**Follow-up question:**

What if you want to keep the gabs in your new vector? For example, if we have:

```
x <- c(5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9)
```

I want it to be:

```
y <- c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```r
match(x, unique(x))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Or

```r
as.numeric(factor(x))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Or

```r
1 + c(0, cumsum(sign(diff(x))))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: What if you want to keep the gabs in your new vector? For example, if we have c(5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9).  I want it to be c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5).

Comment: @Orangemarmalade Wouldn't that just be x - 4? Or x - x[1] + 1?

Comment: @Allen Cameron, it would for this particular case, but what if the numbers over different vectors are a bit more random so that -4 is not always valid for each vector.

Comment: @Orangemarmalade So `x - x[1] + 1`?

Answer (score 3):

`rleid` from `data.table`:

```
x <- c(5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17)
data.table::rleid(x)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Follow-up - to keep the gaps:

```
x - x[1] + 1
#>  [1]  1  1  1  3  3  3  5  7  7  7 11 11 11 13 13 13 13
```